# How should I do correct loop fuction with python Selenium?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am using Webdriver to do crawler. And it really works for the first page and second page, respectively. But when I wrote the loop, it always shows the result of the second pages. My code was attached below. Thank you for your help.

```
for p in range(2):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.wrapper > div > div.column-wrapper.clear-fix > div > section > nav > ul > li:nth-child(9) > a').click()
    soup = bs(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    for ele in soup.select('h3.title a'):
        print(ele.text)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: What do you want to loop through? The range function returns you 0,1 and 2 and then executes the same body on each iteration.

Comment: @Dawid Sorry, I didn't explain clearly. I will do the loop that because there are multiple pages and I need to turn the pages to scrap the information, the code of turning pages where is my second line of code.

Comment: Perhaps at each iteration it returns to your page 1 because you don't overwrite the driver object.